# Maximum brightness is not maximum brightness

Tags: 12.10, display, brightness

On my dual boot laptop I noticed that maximum brightness in Ubuntu and Windows 8 is totally different. In Windows 8 the screen is much much brighter at maximum level than it is at Ubuntu maximum level. (I was even asked why my laptop display looks that dim.)

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad E330 Laptop with Intel HD 4000 graphics.

How can I increase the maximum brightness level Ubuntu uses?

Comment: Same Issue. Even though I don't have dual boot, I've always felt my display to be dim.

Comment: I'll try to take some pictures to show the difference as I think screenshots don't make any sense here.

Comment: Added the information. To give a little update to the described problem: I failed in making some photos, that could show the effect so it's just a subjective impression I have when I look at Ubuntu or Windows. I guess brightness is controlled by the kernel and there's no setting maximum brightness higher than maximum brightness because it's determined by the hardware, or am I wrong?

Comment: try this app , may be it will help you http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/brightness-control-ubuntu

Comment: The mentioned app (brightness control indicator) is just using the system values for brightness and doesn't allow you to increase brightness to a higher value than that.

Comment: Try this app. http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/06/dual-monitor-brightness-controller-2

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu has a preset range of values that it can give to any hardware device and assumes that they all use the same brightness values (which they don't) because the BIOS controls for Ubuntu are poorly coded.

The control is integrated into the window manager and can't be individually configured (same goes for the brightness OSD which can't be disabled without disabling power management altogether).

I filed a bug for this years ago.

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `xrandr`? I had the opposite of your problem, my monitor was too bright and I ended up adjusting it using `xrandr`:

```
xrandr --output VGA1 --gamma 0.7:0.7:0.7 --brightness 0.8
```

you need to replace **VGA1** with your current output, and replace 0.8 and 0.7 by 1.5 for example. by default they are all set to 1.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me, you could give it a try:

1. `$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
2. Replace this line `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` with
   `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"`
3. Save and close
4. `$ sudo update-grub`
5. reboot

Comment: After I did this the brightness was set to minimal and I could no longuer increase the brightness.

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem with my HP 2560p on 16.04. For me it had to do with the light sensor. When I disabled the light sensor in /sys/devices/platform/hp-wmi/als (change 1 to 0) I could increase the brightness higher than before.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend [edit]ing this answer to expand it with specific details about how to do this. (See also [How do I write a good answer?](/help/how-to-answer) for general advice about what sorts of answers are considered most valuable on AskUbuntu.)